# Infinite loop occurs when no return statement is used

Tags: typescript, linked-list, infinite-loop

This is a beginner question.

I have 2 simple classes with the intent to create a Linked List. The append method in my LinkedList class causes an infinite loop if a return statement is not used in its if statement. Can anyone lend some insight as to why that is?

```
class LinkedList {
    head: Nodule;

    append(appendedNodule: Nodule) {
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = appendedNodule;
        }
        let current: Nodule = this.head;
        while (current.next) {
            current = current.next;
        };
        current.next = appendedNodule;

    }
}

class Nodule {
    data: number;
    next: Nodule;
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's execute the code, line by line, for the first node you append:

```
    if (!this.head) {
```

this condition is true: there is no head yet. So the if block is executed

```
        this.head = appendedNodule;
```

so now we have a head node, which is the appended node. There is no return, so we keep executing the method.

```
    }
    let current: Nodule = this.head;
```

And we now also have a local variable `current` which also refers to the head (not null anymore), which also is the appended node.

```
    while (current.next) {
```

The current head has no next node, so the while block is not executed

```
        current = current.next;
```

The instruction above is thus not executed

```
    };
```

But the following one is, since we're not in the while loop anymore

```
    current.next = appendedNodule;
```

And the head now has a next node, and this next node is itself.

So, if we now append another node, the while loop will get the next node, again and again, until it's null. But it will never null, since you've created a loop:

```
 ---------\
 |        | next
 \/       |
current ---
```

Let's execute the same method a second time, line by line:

```
    if (!this.head) {
```

the condition is now false. We have a head node, sow e skip the if block

```
        this.head = appendedNodule;
    }
    let current: Nodule = this.head;
```

The current variable refres to the head node

```
    while (current.next) {
```

This is true, since the head node's next node is itself. So we execute the while block

```
        current = current.next;
```

current becomes the next node. So we test the while condition again. It's still true: the next node is the current node. So we have an infinite loop.

```
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough run-through. Your explanation makes perfect sense. I suppose I was just being thick headed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here lies in the initialization of the LinkedList.  In the beginning, the list is empty:

```
const linkedList = new LinkedList(); // linkedList = {head: undefined}
```

Then when you go to add the first item to the list:

```
linkedList.append(new Nodule(42));
```

The following happens:

```
append(appendedNodule: Nodule) { // appendedNodule = {data: 42, next: undefined}
    if (!this.head) { // Condition evaluates to true, since we just initialized the LinkedList
        this.head = appendedNodule; // linkedList = {head: {data: 42, next: undefined}}
    }
    let current: Nodule = this.head; 
    // current = {data: 42, next: undefined}

    // current.next is undefined, so we skip this loop entirely
    while (current.next) {
        current = current.next;
    };

    // current.next = current now! We've created a circular reference!
    current.next = appendedNodule;

}
```

It seems the problem is in the branching here. If the list is empty, we simply need to define the `head` with the provided `Nodule` instance.  Else, we need to append to the end of the list.  I think wrapping

```
let current: Nodule = this.head;
while (current.next) {
    current = current.next;
};
current.next = appendedNodule;
```

in an `else` block will do the trick :-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and enhancement. I didn't even consider using an else statement. It rids me of having to use a return statement mid-function.